# how to generate a full array of data with range()

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I've been trying to pre-populate an array of data using RxJS but I've hit a brick wall. In the end I've had to revert back to more traditional styles of coding.

You can see in the snippet below, I'm building an array of data and then returning it as stream with `of` (so that it can be `combineLatest` into a vm).

You can also see my failed attempt to use `range()` which is commented out below it.

This almost worked but the return value was a single `BookingMonth` rather than an array.

```js
  public getMonthData(): Observable<BookingMonth[]> {
    const { seasonStart, seasonEnd } = getSeasonDates();

    let monthData: BookingMonth[] = [];
    for (
      let monthNum = seasonStart.getMonth();
      monthNum <= seasonEnd.getMonth();
      monthNum++
    ) {
      const currentMonthStartDate = new Date(2023, monthNum, 1);
      
      monthData.push({
        hasPrevious: seasonStart.getMonth() != monthNum,
        hasNext: seasonEnd.getMonth() != monthNum,
        startDate: currentMonthStartDate,
        endDate: getLastDayOfMonth(2023, monthNum),
        name: getMonthNameFull(currentMonthStartDate),
      });
    }

    return of(monthData);

    // const months$ = range(startDate.getMonth(), endDate.getMonth()).pipe(
    //   map(monthNum => {
    //     const currentMonthStartDate = new Date(2023, monthNum, 0);
    //     return {
    //       hasPrevious: startDate.getMonth() != monthNum,
    //       hasNext: endDate.getMonth() != monthNum,
    //       startDate: currentMonthStartDate,
    //       endDate: getLastDayOfMonth(2023, monthNum),
    //       name: getMonthNameFull(currentMonthStartDate)
    //     }
    //   })
    // );

    // return months$;
  }
```

Is there some way to use `range()` to generate the data and return the array? (Or a better way to stay inside RxJS more?)

Or am I trying to misuse this feature?

Comment: (Totally misread the question the first time, sorry) You can do it with `range` using `toArray`: `return range(startDate.getMonth(), endDate.getMonth()).pipe(map(...)).toArray();`. This will return an observable that collects all the data from the range mapped to the data structure you want and emits them as a single array and then *completes* the observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RxJS's toArray for the same effect.

```ts
return range(startDate.getMonth(), endDate.getMonth()).pipe(
  map(monthNum => ({
    monthNum, 
    currentMonthStartDate: new Date(2023, monthNum, 0)
  })),
  map(({monthNum, currentMonthStartDate}) => ({
    hasPrevious: startDate.getMonth() != monthNum,
    hasNext: endDate.getMonth() != monthNum,
    startDate: currentMonthStartDate,
    endDate: getLastDayOfMonth(2023, monthNum),
    name: getMonthNameFull(currentMonthStartDate),
  })),
  toArray()
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I incorporated the code and it does just what I need. I've already applied the concept of doing an operator to build up the next operator as well, which was a new concept for me with this snippet.